# Filter the selected data

Tags: angular, typescript

There are two "select" and two blocks. The information in the blocks should be displayed depending on  the select. When you select a specific user in the" select " list, the first block displays information about that user. And if in the second "select" to choose a certain date in the second block will display all the posts for the selected date of the selected user.

Here is my code, but it does not work, who can help to fix it?

html:

```
<select   (change)="onSelectedUser(user.value)">
  <option  *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.user_id">
    {{user.name}}
  </option>
</select>
<select  (change)="onSelectedYear(d.value)">
  <option type="number"  *ngFor="let d of dates">
     {{ d.dates }}
  </option>
 </select>

<div *ngIf="userId">
   <form>
     <label class="control-label">Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='user.name' name="name" disabled>
     <label class="control-label">E-mail</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='user.email' name="email" disabled>
     <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='user.phone' name="phone" disabled>
   </form>
</div>
<div *ngIf="date">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let post of filteredposts">
         <td>{{post.post_text}}</td>
         <td>{{post.dates}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

ts:

```
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  users: Array<User>;
  dates: Array<Date>;
  posts: Array<Post>;

  public filteredPosts: Post[];
  private _posts: Post[];

  constructor(
    public authTokenService: Angular2TokenService, 
    private servUser: UserService,
    private servDate: DateService,
    private servPost: PostService
  ) { 
    this.dates = new Array<Date>();
    this.users = new Array<User>();
    this.posts = new Array<Post>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._filtered(this.users, this.dates);
    this.loadUsers();
    this.loadPosts();
    this.loadDates();

  }

  private loadUsers() {
    this.servUser.getUsers().subscribe(users => this.users = users);
  }

  private loadDates() {
    this.servDate.getDates().subscribe(dates => this.dates = dates);
  }

  private loadPost() {
    this.servPost.getPosts().subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts);

  }


  public onSelectedUser(userId: User[]): void {
    this._filtered(userId, this.dates);
  }

  public onSelectedDate(date: Date[]): void {
    this._filtered(this.users, date);
  }

  private _filtered(userId: User[], date: Date[]): void {
    let filteredPosts: Post[] = this._posts;
    if (userId) {
      filteredPosts = filteredPosts.filter((post: Post) => post.p_users_id === +userId);
    }
    if (year) {
      filteredPosts = filteredPosts.filter((post: Post) => post.dates === +date);
    }
    this.filteredPosts = filteredPosts;
  }


}
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
>
> at PostsComponent._filtered (posts.component.ts:87)
>
> at PostsComponent.ngOnInit (posts.component.ts:54)

Comment: @Chellappan Sorry but no I have proxy blocks this site

Comment: "it does not work" is much, much too vague. Especially if you don't post somethign we can reproduce. Be much more specific than that.

Comment: @JBNizet I updated the question

Comment: What is unclear in the error message? You define a function accepting a number as argument, and you pass it an array of Date instead. How could that possibly work?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ngModel` in the select.

```
  <select (change)="onSelectedUser(selectedUser)" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser">
    <option  *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.user_id">
      {{user.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
    <select (change)="onSelectedDate(selectedDate)" [(ngModel)]="selectedDate">
    <option  *ngFor="let date of dates" [value]="date">
      {{date}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <div *ngFor="let p of filteredPosts">
      {{p.post}}
  </div>
```

This is a simple example.

```
  selectedUser:number;
  selectedDate:number;
  users=[{name:'A',user_id:1},{name:'B',user_id:2}]
  dates=[1,2,3];
  posts=[{user_id:1,date:1,post:"qqqq"},
  {user_id:1,date:1,post:"adcs"},
  {user_id:1,date:2,post:"dssd"},
  {user_id:1,date:3,post:"jkjk"},
  {user_id:2,date:1,post:"zzzzz"}];

  filteredPosts=[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

 public onSelectedUser(userId:number): void {
    this._filtered(userId, this.selectedDate);
  }

  public onSelectedDate(date: number): void {
    this._filtered(this.selectedUser, date);
  }

  private _filtered(userId: number, date: number): void {
    this.filteredPosts=[];
    if (userId && date) {
      this.filteredPosts = this.posts.filter((post: any) => post.user_id == userId);
      this.filteredPosts = this.filteredPosts.filter((post: any) => post.date == date);
    }
    else if (userId) {
      this.filteredPosts = this.posts.filter((post: any) => post.user_id == userId);
    }
    else if (date) {
      this.filteredPosts = this.posts.filter((post: any) => post.date == date);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of your calls in `ngOnInit` is the matter. You call  `this._filtered(this.users, this.dates);` even before load the data into `this.users` and `this.dates`. That is why your are getting **`"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"`**. Try to call `this._filtered(this.users, this.dates);` after loaded data into  `this.users` and `this.dates`

Hope this helps to you!